# getElementById(Variable) Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to use a variable `aaa` with a simple string for `getElementById`.
But it doesn't work. I have tested the result of `aaa` via an input box.
Maybe it has some spaces at the end or the beginning but it doesn't look like.

If I type the element ID manually into `getElementById` it works. What's happening? 
I've allready tried `.tostring()` but that didn't help either.

```
function slideActivity(tagId,width,heigth,topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft,picArray){

    var aaa = tagId.replace("#","");
    document.getElementById('script').value = aaa;

    var container = document.getElementById(aaa);
```

Comment: Please show us with which values you call this function (especially `tagId`) and how your DOM/markup looks like. Also it would be nice to see the entire code, you're at least missing a closing `}`

Comment: We can't help unless we see your markup and the inputs to your function.

Comment: You should also try to work on the syntax of your question. It's very hard to read.

Comment: Do you have an element with the id "script", or are you trying to access a specific script tag?

Comment: script is used in html for JavaScript and others, I would use a different name. `document.getElementById('script')` may not get what you think it does.

Comment: @revent—what do you think it will get other than an element with an id of "script" or `null`?

Comment: I think `script` is the input box he used to debug as mentioned in the question. That worked as expected if I understood correctly.

Comment: If you are sure about what aaa is then try this `var container = document.getElementById("'"+aaa+"'");`